# Querying Database to retrieve all the records containing a given string in an array of strings present in the record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I'm having an Active Record in my rails application in which each row of the table MyTable contains:

1. stringArr            --> an array of string
2. id

Now I want to query my database to pull all the records in which a particular `queryString` is present in `strinArr` of that record.

I know we can do `MyTable.where(xyz:someXYZ)` to pull all the records with `xyz` value as `someXYZ`?

But how can I do this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch all record, which contains `queryString` in an array of records, you can do -

```
MyTable.where("column_name LIKE ?","'%queryString%'"})
```

This will do exact query string search means return all data, which `column_name` contains `queryString`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sql like clause

```
MyTable.where("stringArr LIKE :keywords",{keywords: '%querystring%'})
```

Comment: can you plz write it in the form of stringArr and queryString and explain what exactly it is doing?
Thank you btw

Comment: and i think we should also use "include?" method to check if queryString is present in stringArr

Comment: @user3166642  `include?` returns true or false only instead of all the records.

Comment: the like operator is a feature in sql where you can match a record by a subset of the data. You can learn it here 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp
eg: name like %mat% 
would match a record with name "mathew" notice the string matches a subset